# Bouncing ball simulation

Tags: javascript, animation, physics, processing.js

I was fooling around with some maths and realized that I could use a parabola to represent a bouncing ball. So, naturally, I decided to make it in code.

```javascript
var Ball = function(r, v, a, y, x) {
    this.r = r;
    this.v = v;
    this.a = a;
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.y = this.v*this.r*this.r + this.a*this.r;
    var NewBallY = 380 - this.y;
    ellipse(this.x, NewBallY, 20, 20);
    if(this.y < 0) {
        this.r = 0;}
    this.r += 2;
};

var Ball1 = new Ball(0, random(-0.05, -0.02), random(2.0, 6.0), 40, random(20, 380));
var Ball2 = new Ball(0, random(-0.05, -0.02), random(2.0, 6.0), 40, random(20, 380));
var Ball3 = new Ball(0, random(-0.05, -0.02), random(2.0, 6.0), 40, random(20, 380));

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    Ball1.draw();
    Ball2.draw();
    Ball3.draw();
};
```

The equation I used to calculate the parabola representing a ball's \$y\$ position is here, where \$y\$ is the `y` position of the ball, \$V\$ is the velocity, \$A\$ is the acceleration, and \$r\$ is the amount of time passed since the start of the bounce:

$$y=Vr^{2}+Ar$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `this.r` to represent elapsed time is highly unconventional.  I would have guessed that `r` stood for "radius".  Why not use `this.t` like a sane programmer?

The `draw()` function ends with `this.r += 2;`, which is odd.  Why should the drawing routine manage the passage of time?  I would expect the time to be managed either in reference to the wall clock or to be passed in as a parameter by whatever code calls `draw()`.

---

These don't look like parabolas to me.  At best, they would be degenerate ones, since `this.x` never changes.

---

The placement of the closing brace here:

```
if(this.y < 0) {
    this.r = 0;}
```

is weird.  Conventional formatting would be:

```
if (this.y < 0) {
    this.r = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- Regular variables and properties are `camelCase`, only constructor functions are `PascalCase`. So `Ball` is named well, but `Ball1`, `Ball2`, `Ball3` and `NewBallY` should all just be `camelCase` (i.e. `ball1`, `newBallY` etc.).
- Like 200_success above, I have no idea why `r` should represent "time", or why it's incremented by precisely 2 each iteration.
- In general, I'm not a fan of 1-letter variables, the exceptions being things like `x` and `y`. Of course, forgetting the "`r` stands for 'elapsed time'" nonsense, things like `v` and `a` are, I'd say, allowable shorthands because of the context. However, the constructor arguments don't need to use those shorthands, and can be descriptive. E.g.

  ```
  function Ball(startTime, initialVelocity, acceleration, x, y)
  ```
- However, why is `r`/time an argument (the first even) to your constructor? I can understand wanting to make the elapsed time configurable, but you can always just write `ball.r = <some value>;`. Your instantiation of `Ball1` etc. doesn't use the argument for anything, so it seems like should just be left out.
- What *isn't* settable (at all) from the outside is the size of the ball, though that, along with initial position, is be the minimum you'd need to draw it. So perhaps *that* should be a constructor argument. But the size is hardcoded within the `draw` function (which, as 200_success points out, also seems to doing more than just drawing)
- Similarly, the height of the canvas/screen (380) is hard-coded inside `draw`

Comment: The reason `r` is incremented by two each time is because if it was incremented by any less, the simulation would be less realistic.

Comment: @EthanBierlein That's not "time's fault" - if you use different values for `v` and `a` you'll get a "realistic" result too.

Answer (score 5):

Your formula for the height of the ball is wrong. The height of a ball at time \$t\$ acting only under gravity is
$$y(t) = y_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2.$$
\$y_0\$ is the initial height, \$v_0\$ is the initial velocity, and \$a\$ is the acceleration (\$-9.8\,\,m/s^2\$ for Earth gravity). For the bounce, you'll need to find some way to reverse the ball's velocity when its height is zero.